# Why doesn't Posgres parse Arabic tokens correctly (using ts_debug)?

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

PostgreSQL has a few features related to full-text search. It knows how to parse a string into tokens (see [parsers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-parsers.html)). For instance, here is how it parses `Hello, friends and contributors.` into tokens:

```
# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('Hello, friends.');
   alias   |   description   |  token  |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  | lexemes  
-----------+-----------------+---------+----------------+--------------+----------
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | Hello   | {english_stem} | english_stem | {hello}
 blank     | Space symbols   | ,       | {}             |              | 
 asciiword | Word, all ASCII | friends | {english_stem} | english_stem | {friend}
 blank     | Space symbols   | .       | {}             |              | 
(4 rows)
```

On my Ubuntu machine, this can handle Arabic just as well, as you can see here. Even if you can't read Arabic, you can see that it parsed out each Arabic word into a separate Arabic word token:

```
# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('واحد اثنين ثلاثة');
 alias |    description    | token |  dictionaries  |  dictionary  | lexemes 
-------+-------------------+-------+----------------+--------------+---------
 word  | Word, all letters | واحد  | {english_stem} | english_stem | {واحد}
 blank | Space symbols     |       | {}             |              | 
 word  | Word, all letters | اثنين | {english_stem} | english_stem | {اثنين}
 blank | Space symbols     |       | {}             |              | 
 word  | Word, all letters | ثلاثة | {english_stem} | english_stem | {ثلاثة}
(5 rows)
```

But on my macOS machine, it doesn't seem to be able to parse Arabic words into separate Arabic tokens at all, it seems to think that all Arabic characters are whitespace:

```
# SELECT * FROM ts_debug('واحد اثنين ثلاثة');
 alias |  description  |      token       | dictionaries | dictionary | lexemes 
-------+---------------+------------------+--------------+------------+---------
 blank | Space symbols | واحد اثنين ثلاثة | {}           |            | 
(1 row)
```

How do I get Postgres to parse `واحد اثنين ثلاثة` into three word tokens (as well as whitespace tokens)?

---

## Possible clue

The documentation does say this:

> The parser's notion of a “letter” is determined by the database's locale setting, specifically `lc_ctype`. Words containing only the basic ASCII letters are reported as a separate token type, since it is sometimes useful to distinguish them. In most European languages, token types word and asciiword should be treated alike.

My `LC_CTYPE` is set like this:

```
# SHOW LC_CTYPE;
  lc_ctype   
-------------
 en_GB.UTF-8
(1 row)
```

However, this doesn't explain why on Ubuntu parsing Arabic works, but no on macOS. If I attempt to create a database with an Arabic locale on macOS, I get this error:

```
$ createdb --locale ar_AR.utf8 -T template0 hello
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  invalid locale name: "ar_AR.utf8"
```

Comment: use `dpkg-reconfigure locales` to add `ar_AR.utf8` locale to your os. After that restart postgres. Finally try to create database in arabic language.

Comment: @SahapAsci This doesn't work on macOS.

Comment: can you check the locale? Use command `locale -a | grep _AR` in your mac

Comment: @SahapAsci I tried this on my macOS machine, and there is no Arabic locale installed.

Comment: Did you tried to create db after you install Arabic locale?

Comment: @SahapAsci How do you install the Arabic locale on macOS? I don't know of a way.

Comment: Well I am not a mac user but after a 30 sec search I found [this](https://www.apple.com/shop/question/answers/readonly/does-mac-os-x-106-support-arabic-language/QYDXJYCYTKC7UY7JX) link

Comment: @SahapAsci Your link shows one how to add an Arabic input source in macOS, which I have already done. It doesn't add Arabic to the list printed by `locale -a`, so it's not a help here.

Comment: I think this question became more than a MacOS question rather than a postgresql one.